# Unix tab tab equivalent?

Tags: linux, unix, tabs, ssh

So using (tab)(tab) in the bash is a cool autocomplete feature. However, here's my situation; when I type e.g. ssh(tab)(tab), it will display all the sshs I have but I have no way of greping from there. Is there a command to replace the (tab)(tab) or an ssh option to see them all and then grep from there? Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I was missing the tabs, apparently the higher-than and lower-than signs are reserved

Comment: just type another letter or two to disambiguate and tab again.

Comment: grep?    you can use visual grep 1.0 ... comes preinstalled in most humans.   Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to accomplish exactly what you're asking, but instead you could possibly use the find command:

```
find /usr/bin -iname "ssh*keygen"
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need more info. What completion are you using for ssh? What does `complete | grep ssh` say?

If it's hosts, you can use the hosts-complete keypress - I think alt-@ - anywhere, including after a grep. If it's something else, you'll need to figure out how to instantiate your completion some other way.